# Why does typescript resolve a union type to possible empty string when using logic operators?

Tags: typescript, logical-operators, union-types

I am trying to guard against a null object using logic operators. The object which might be null contains a string and a union type as attributes. If I use "&&" operator to check if the object is not null, the whole expression is evaluated to another union type, which allows empty strings, and I have a type mismatch error.

I've verified that if instead of using the logic operator, I use an IF statement, the code works fine, but I want to understand why is it not being resolved as I expected.

```js
type FooType = 'aaa' | 'bbb' | 'ccc';
​
interface IFoo {
  type: FooType;
  id: string;
}
​
type FooAlias = IFoo;
​
const fooObject = {type: 'aaa', id: '111'} as IFoo;
​
const fooObject2: FooAlias = {
  id: fooObject && fooObject.id,
  type: fooObject && fooObject.type
  /* The line above complains:
  Type '"" | "aaa" | "bbb" | "ccc"' is not assignable to type 'FooType'.
  Type '""' is not assignable to type 'FooType'.ts(2322)*/
};
```

if instead of `type: fooObject && fooObject.type` I use `type: fooObject? fooObject.type : null` it works, because it seems like it correctly dos not assume it might be an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32455). If `strictNullChecks` are off an extra `""` sneaks in.

Until this gets fixed you can use a type assertion or a ternary operator:

```
const fooObject2: FooAlias = {
  id: fooObject && fooObject.id,
  //type: (fooObject && fooObject.type) as FooType
  type: fooObject ? fooObject.type : undefined
};
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAKuaBeKByAhjjUA+mARiXoRgMZUYDcAsAFCDQBIwJYB2wEATgGZYVoASXhwoAb0ZQooSAC5YCZJHoNprACYKAzsG4cA5qoC+jFg1nRRAQQA2rLNqjoRCVeYpx2uqLwQB5IgArCApgZwlLBWxcABooTWiARhSMYyhHKFc4VSkoRk9vcL84QJCwgCYFG3tM9Ek1BK1fAODQ8IAyDpbStrCAOk1YvIB6EaioAAoSsvaoLp7ZgcsASgynUWUIPImZvvCAfkX9-ssoBQBXdg0IXg4IDUZjGiA)